# openldap and root password

Tags: ldap, openldap

I recently changed my root password, but when I restart Ldap (openldap-2.2.13) I couldn't log in with Ldap users to any application that is on this server.

in /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log I can find a lot of error like:

`[Tue Jun 01 02:27:24 2010] [warn] [client 89.138.98.214] [26762] auth_ldap authenticate: user foo authentication failed; URI /svn-clients/clients/myclient/ [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Can't contact LDAP server]`

I guess there is a linkage between user root and the Ldap configuration, I also changed the 
`rootpw` entry in `slapd.conf`, but this doesn't seem to make things better.

Comment: well, I solved the problem eventually myself. I run slapd with "-d 255" only to discover that bdb_db_open failed. 
executing db_recover fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The server is not running. I would restart on the commandline and immediately check for error messages in /var/log/daemon.log